# Ajax function for multiple id's, reducing redundancy

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I'm kinda baffled as to why these functions are not working the same. In a nutshell, I have 6 tabs (each with unique id's) that each perform basically the same ajax call (displaying data into a div in a tab). I currently have them written out as 6 different ajax functions.

As separate functions, they work as expected. However, if I attempt to make one generic function and attach it to the 6 id's, it does not work.

Here are the six functions that work as expected.

```
    $("#hwTab1").click(function () {
        $("#hwTab1Tab, #hwTab2Tab, #hwTab3Tab, #hwTab4Tab, #hwTab5Tab, #hwTab6Tab").hide();
        $('#hwTab1Tab').show();
        $.when(
            $.get('/api/sitecore/HwTabsWrapper/HwTabsWrapperCtrl?Tab=HwTab1&pv=/Views/Components/_HwTabsWrapperCtrl.cshtml', function (data3) {
                $('#hwTab1Content').html(data3);
            })
        );
    });

    $("#hwTab2").click(function () {
        $("#hwTab1Tab, #hwTab2Tab, #hwTab3Tab, #hwTab4Tab, #hwTab5Tab, #hwTab6Tab").hide();
        $('#hwTab2Tab').show();
        $.when(
            $.get('/api/sitecore/HwTabsWrapper/HwTabsWrapperCtrl?Tab=HwTab2&pv=/Views/Components/_HwTabsWrapperCtrl.cshtml', function (data) {
                $('#hwTab2Content').html(data);
            })
        );
    });

    $("#hwTab3").click(function () {
        $("#hwTab1Tab, #hwTab2Tab, #hwTab3Tab, #hwTab4Tab, #hwTab5Tab, #hwTab6Tab").hide();
        $('#hwTab3Tab').show();
        $.when(
            $.get('/api/sitecore/HwTabsWrapper/HwTabsWrapperCtrl?Tab=HwTab3&pv=/Views/Components/_HwTabsWrapperCtrl.cshtml', function (data3) {
                $('#hwTab3Content').html(data3);
            })
        );
    });

    $("#hwTab4").click(function () {
        $("#hwTab1Tab, #hwTab2Tab, #hwTab3Tab, #hwTab4Tab, #hwTab5Tab, #hwTab6Tab").hide();
        $('#hwTab4Tab').show();
        $.when(
            $.get('/api/sitecore/HwTabsWrapper/HwTabsWrapperCtrl?Tab=HwTab4&pv=/Views/Components/_HwTabsWrapperCtrl.cshtml', function (data3) {
                $('#hwTab4Content').html(data3);
            })
        );
    });

    $("#hwTab5").click(function () {
        $("#hwTab1Tab, #hwTab2Tab, #hwTab3Tab, #hwTab4Tab, #hwTab5Tab, #hwTab6Tab").hide();
        $('#hwTab5Tab').show();
        $.when(
            $.get('/api/sitecore/HwTabsWrapper/HwTabsWrapperCtrl?Tab=HwTab5&pv=/Views/Components/_HwTabsWrapperCtrl.cshtml', function (data3) {
                $('#hwTab5Content').html(data3);
            })
        );
    });

    $("#hwTab6").click(function () {
        $("#hwTab1Tab, #hwTab2Tab, #hwTab3Tab, #hwTab4Tab, #hwTab5Tab, #hwTab6Tab").hide();
        $('#hwTab6Tab').show();
        $.when(
            $.get('/api/sitecore/HwTabsWrapper/HwTabsWrapperCtrl?Tab=HwTab6&pv=/Views/Components/_HwTabsWrapperCtrl.cshtml', function (data3) {
                $('#hwTab6Content').html(data3);
            })
        );
    });
```

As you can see, there is a lot of redundancy in the code. So here's my attempt to make a reusable function.

```
    $(document).on("click", "#hwTab1, #hwTab2, #hwTab3, #hwTab4, #hwTab5, #hwTab6", function () {
        $("#hwTab1Tab, #hwTab2Tab, #hwTab3Tab, #hwTab4Tab, #hwTab5Tab, #hwTab6Tab").hide();
        var linkIDtmp = $(this).attr('id');
        var linkTmp = "#" + linkIDtmp + "Tab";
        $(linkTmp).show();

        var divTmp = '#' + linkIDtmp + 'content';
        $.when(
            $.get('/api/sitecore/HwTabsWrapper/HwTabsWrapperCtrl?Tab=HwTab2&pv=/Views/Components/_HwTabsWrapperCtrl.cshtml', function (data) {
                $(divTmp).html(data);
            })
        );
    });
```

What's confusing to me, is the top 6 functions work, while the bottom function doesn't (data is not displayed in div on page), and I've poured over it, and it seems like it "should" work, so there must be some basic ajax process I'm missing here.

Appreciate any suggestions on this.

thanks!

Comment: Perhaps "content" needs to be capitalized, like in your first example. E.g. `var divTmp = '#' + linkIDtmp + 'Content'`.

Comment: I'd also suggest using classes to attach the event handlers and hide the tabs. It's simpler code and far more extensible. Also `$.when()` is redundant.

Comment: Could you show me an example of what you're talking about Rory? sounds interesting.. and how is the when redundant? It's what's making the ajax call, so I'm definitely interested in learning more about your suggestion.

Comment: @Nick do not edit an answer and add further question to it. If you have a new problem, then create a new question for that problem. If the answer does not target/solve the problem this question is about, then write a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that. Placed my comment into the wrong place. But yes, perhaps a new question would be better.

Comment: @Nick I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example you use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", "#hwTab1,
```

You register the event listener on the `document` element and you tell jQuery that it should only call the eventhandler if the click happend on `"#hwTab1, ...`. The `this` referes always to the element on which the event handler was registered on, and that is the `document` element, because of that you always as for the `id` of the `document`.

You need to use the event target instead:

```
$(document).on("click", "#hwTab1, #hwTab2, #hwTab3, #hwTab4, #hwTab5, #hwTab6", 
  function (evt) { // add the event parameter here
    $("#hwTab1Tab, #hwTab2Tab, #hwTab3Tab, #hwTab4Tab, #hwTab5Tab, #hwTab6Tab").hide();
    var linkIDtmp = $(evt.target).attr('id'); // use evt.target instead of this
    var linkTmp = "#" + linkIDtmp + "Tab";
    $(linkTmp).show();

    var divTmp = '#' + linkIDtmp + 'Content';
    var tabName = linkIDtmp[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + linkIDtmp[0].substr(1,mode.length)       

    $.get('/api/sitecore/HwTabsWrapper/HwTabsWrapperCtrl?Tab=' + tabName + 
            '&pv=/Views/Components/_HwTabsWrapperCtrl.cshtml', 
    function (data) {
       $(divTmp).html(data);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for updating this, however I get a mode is not defined error when I attempt to run this.  I guess it's not happy about the mode.length line?

Comment: actually the more I study this, more I'm unclear on the purpose of this line. var tabName = linkIDtmp[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + linkIDtmp[0].substr(1,mode.length)  is it just to convert the first char in the variable to upper case?

Comment: Actually i got it working. Instead of converting the variable to uppercase, I just made everything uppercase in my html, removed that bit, and then rmoved the spacing around the concatenation, and it worked! :)  thanks for the push in the right direction!